# Is there anyway to reference the collection of parameters passed to a stored procedure, without referencing each one by name?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, metaprogramming

Is there any way to reference the **collection** of parameters passed to a stored proc, without referencing each one by name?

The context here is error logging. I'd like to develop a generic CATCH clause, or sub-clause, that grabs all parameter values as well as other error and execution info and logs it to a table (one or more).

The basic version looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Proc1 @Param1 INT, @Param2 INT
AS
BEGIN TRY
  SELECT 1/0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE @params XML
  SET @params = (
    SELECT 
      @Param1 AS [Param1]
    , @Param2 AS [Param2]
    FOR XML PATH('params'), TYPE
    )
  EXEC dbo.LogError @procid = @@PROCID, @params = @params
  EXEC dbo.RethrowError
END CATCH
```

Now, this template does work, except that for each individual procedure, I would have to edit the `SET @params` section manually.

I could script it out easily enough, but then I would still need to copy it in.

I could leave some sort of placeholder, and then dynamically update each definition w/ a correct `SET` statement. I could even write a database trigger that listens for CREATE and ALTER PROC statements and have it do this for me automagically.

But what I really want is just to grab the collection of parameters directly and be done with it. Is there any way?

**EDIT**: getting parameter metadata from the system tables is not enough. For example:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 
  'SET @params = (SELECT '
+ STUFF((
    SELECT ', '+name+' AS '+STUFF(name,1,1,'') 
    FROM sys.parameters WHERE object_id = @@PROCID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,2,'')
+ ' FOR XML PATH(''params''), TYPE)'
-- inline execute here....alas, there's isn't a mode for that
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@params XML OUTPUT', @params OUTPUT
```

This, of course, generates an error, since I haven't declared parameters for the nested scope of `sp_executesql`. While I could script out the second param of `sp_executesql`, I can't assign them without explicitly assigning them one at a time by name.

**Original question, rephrased**: is there another flavor of `sp_executesql` that inherits variable "context" from the outer scope, that executes in the same frame, that inlines the command, rather than executing in a nested scope?

Comment: For what version of SQL Server?  Table variables or User Defined Types *might* do what you want, but you still have to populate them.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, any way I approach it right now I can't get away from explicit variable references *somewhere*. Why doesn't T-SQL have a $frame or $variables special var? Alas.

Comment: @Peter: Your desired approach is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen--SQL/TSQL is protecting you from yourself.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Show me the attack vector introduced by a $frame special var that doesn't already exist. We aren't executing arbitrary code. `EXEC ()` and `sp_executesql` already provide that vector handily.

Comment: `EXEC` nor `sp_executesql` stop me from passing `DELETE FROM USER`/etc.  Neither will validate the SQL prior to running it...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: we're talking at cross purposes. I can get the input buffer and set options from `DBCC` calls. I can get the current user and whether he's impersonating someone else from system functions. I can get the currently executing SPID and proc from `@@SPID` and `@@PROCID` respectively. I **can't** get whether a parameter value was a) supplied by the user or b) provided by a default. I can't get parameter values as a collection. I can't tell much of anything about the current execution context. ie, limited self-inspection. A $params var that returned an XML document would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sql_handle) to retrieve the SQL command, using sys.sysprocesses.sql_handle?

Comment: That only returns the text of currently executing batch. It doesn't provide the parameter values of the batch.